# Polymer: Style different core-icon-buttons differently

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I want to add two core-icon buttons one right-top of a (custom) post-card polymer component and the other at the bottom-center. How do I do this? The current code applies to both the core-icon-buttons (below). Is there a way to qualify the styling of core-icon-button by the icon type?

```
<template>
  <style>
....
  core-icon-button { 
      content: '.icon clear';
      position: absolute;
      top: 3px;
      right: 3px;
      color: blue;
    }
....
</style>


<core-icon-button icon="clear"></core-icon-button>
<core-icon-button icon="thumb-up"></core-icon-button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are free to use standard well-known HTML elements’ ids/classes for that:

```
<template>
  <style>
    .clearbtn { color: white }
    #thumbupbtn { left: 100px }
  </style>

  <core-icon-button class="clearbtn" icon="clear"></core-icon-button>
  <core-icon-button id="thumpupbtn" icon="thumb-up"></core-icon-button>
</template>
```

You might as well use CSS selectors for that:

```
<style>
  core-icon-button[icon="clear"] { color: white }
  core-icon-button[icon="thumb-up"] { left: 100px }
</style>
```

Hope it helps.